# How to check for numbers only (including negative)?

Tags: php, numbers, negative-number

how can I check for numbers only from -10 negative to +10 positive?

This is what I have, but I think it's not safe:

```
if(isset($_POST['number']) && ctype_digit($_POST['number']) && $_POST['number']>=-10 && $_POST['number']<=10){
    //do something
}
```

and the form:

```
Input a number between -10 and 10: <input type="text" name="number" size="5" />
```

Comment: I added the php tag so that the php community can see your question.

Comment: Why would you want people to type it when it is such a finite number? why not add a select box?

Answer (score 2):

```
if( isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $num = intval($_POST['number']);
    if( $num >= -10 && $num <= 10) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

There are other ways, but that one will work. Anything that can't be converted to a number will be treated as zero. If this is not desired behaviour, add:

```
&& "".$num == $_POST['number']
```

To that inner IF statement, to ensure that no non-numeric characters were removed from the input.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether a variable is a number including zero and negative values

```
$x = '-22';
if (isNumber($x, ['zero','negative']))
    echo 'Yes';
else
    echo 'No';

isNumber($x, $includes=[])
{       
    if (is_int($x)) {
        if ($x === 0) {
            if (in_array('zero', $includes))
                return true;
        } elseif ($x < 0) {
            if (in_array('negative', $includes))
                return true;
        } else
            return true;
    } elseif (is_string($x)) {
        if ($x == '0') {
            if (in_array('zero', $includes))
                return true;
        } elseif ($x[0] == '-') {
            if (in_array('negative', $includes))
                return ctype_digit(substr($x, 1));
        } else
            return ctype_digit($x);
    }
}
```